# salesforce report to list all the schedule dashboards with there times

Tags: dashboard

I am wondering how to find all the scheduled dashboards with there times.
It would be very helpful to have a filtered list view for dashboards or some other method to show this information directly from Salesforce with a click or two.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

If you Go to setup|administration setup|monitoring|Scheduled Jobs.
Here you will find the list of all scheduled jobs in your org. 
Or simply type "Scheduled" in Quick Find search box and then click on "Scheduled Jobs".
Just like any other listview, you can filter or create a new view to see all schedule dashboards in your org.
Hope this answer your question.